# How to create custom connector with dynamic URI in power automate?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I have one Postman collection and I have created a custom connector using that collection. All is working well but one request has URI as in the below image.

[image]

where **urn%3Ali%3Aimage%3AD5622AQEcyXncoACqYw** part is dynamic and it will change for every new request. In the custom connector it took **https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/urn%3Ali%3Aimage%3AD5622AQEcyXncoACqYw** as URI and does not allow me to add **urn%3Ali%3Aimage%3AD5622AQEcyXncoACqYw** dynamically like image below.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `1. General`, set the following:
[image]

Under `2. Definition`, set the following:
[image]

You add parameters by adding `{paramName}` in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I see in "[Power Platform / Connectors / Create a custom connector from scratch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank)" a section "[Step 4: (Optional) Enable your connector as an AI plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank#step-4-optional-enable-your-connector-as-an-ai-plugin)" where you can define parameters for your connector:

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/media/define-blank/plugin-parameters.png]

So, when defining your custom connector, you would need to specify the URL structure in a way that can accept dynamic segments. For example, if your base URL is `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/`, you can define the dynamic part as a path parameter like `{imageId}`.

In your custom connector definition, you would have something like this:

```bash
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/{imageId}
```

So, when defining your custom connector, you would need to specify the URL structure in a way that can accept dynamic segments. For example, if your base URL is `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/`, you can define the dynamic part as a path parameter like `{imageId}`.

In your custom connector definition, you would have something like this:

```bash
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/{imageId}
```

When you [use this connector in a flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/use-custom-connector-flow), you will provide the dynamic part of the URL, `urn%3Ali%3Aimage%3AD5622AQEcyXncoACqYw`, as the value for the `imageId` parameter.

```bash
imageId: urn%3Ali%3Aimage%3AD5622AQEcyXncoACqYw
```